# How to calculate due date based on term selection in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a credit term dropdown list where the user will select and I want to calculate the due date based on the selection and the start date. How do I calculate the date and the result will generate in the textbox of due date?
For example:

1. Start Date: 01-05-2021 Credit term: 30days Due Date will be: 31-05-2021
2. Start Date: 01-05-2021 Credit term: 45days Due Date will be: 15-06-2021
3. Start Date: 01-05-2021 Credit term: 90days Due Date will be: 30-06-2021
4. Start Date: 01-05-2021 Credit term: 30days Due Date will be: 30-07-2021
5. Start Date: 01-05-2021 Credit term: 30days Due Date will be: 27-11-2021

```js
$('#CalculateDate').on('click', function() {
  var days = $('#term').val();
  var dueDate = new Date($('#txtStartDate').val());
  dueDate.setDate(dueDate.getDate() + days);
  $('#txtDueDate').val((dueDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + dueDate.getDate() + '/' + dueDate.getFullYear());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Start Date: </label><input type="date" id="txtStartDate" />
<br/><br/>
<label>Credit Term</label>
<select id="term">
  <option label="Choose One"></option>
  <option value="1">C.O.D</option>
  <option value="30">30 days</option>
  <option value="45">45 days</option>
  <option value="60">60 days</option>
  <option value="90">90 days</option>
  <option value="210">210 days</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<label>Due Date: </label><input type="text" id="txtDueDate" />
<button id="CalculateDate">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Hi, I have added my calculate function. The problem that I faced is that the calculation for due date is wrong when I select the term.

Comment: Your  code is almost right just change `$('#term').val()` to `parseInt($('#term').val())`

Comment: @Swati, Hi Swati. If you're interested, I'd like to ask for your assistance with this issue. Maybe you have any idea for this issue? [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67465554/is-it-possible-to-set-child-as-parent-for-dynamic-table-row-in-jquery-and-calcul)

Answer (score 0):

You can use datapicker

```
var datValue = $('select').val();
$( '#datepicker' ).datepicker();
$('select').change( function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate','+' + datValue + 'd').datepicker('show');
});
```